# Learning react and this doesn't look right

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm creating an account creation page where someone can sign up for a website. I wouldn't actually use this for anything other than learning react (firebase auth ftw). I come from a java background.

I couldn't figure out how to get the lastest user data per click, so I got it to work this way, but it feels janky. Can someone help me with it? I feel like I shouldn't need a username or an email state, but just one user state. Then the handlers should just be setting the user state, but that doesn't work either.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

function usernameHandler(event) {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
    setUser('username', event.target.value);
}

function emailHandler(event) {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
    setUser('email', event.target.value);
}

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(email, username);

    // setUser({'email': email, 'username': username});

    console.log(user);

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/user/');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // setData(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ "email": email, "username": username }));
}
```

I tried moving the setUser to handle submit, which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: While the XHR Ajax Request may work, its important to stay up to date with the latest standards. you might be better off using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: Ah great, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiple states if you need different independent behaviours, e.g. display different validation messages.

You can use a single state object like:

```js
function MyForm() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        email: "",
        username: "",
    });

    function onInput(event) {
        setData((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        }));
    }

    async function onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // use window.fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest
        const response = await fetch("...", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        // do something with the response
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input
                name="email"
                type="email"
                required
                onInput={onInput}
                value={data.email}
            />
            <input
                name="username"
                type="text"
                required
                onInput={onInput}
                value={data.username}
            />
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

The important bit is `[event.target.name]: event.target.value`: it updates the state dynamically, based on the `name` attribute of the input (that should be named like in the state object).

If you don't need to update anything in the UI, you can skip the state entirely:

```js
function MyForm() {
    async function onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = Object.from(new FormData(event.target));
        const response = await fetch("...", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        // do something with the response
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input name="email" type="email" required />
            <input name="username" type="text" required />
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: Ohh this is awesome, thank you. Should submit handler always be async, if there's an API call?

Yeah, I'm just creating the registration page. Next week, I'll try to work on routing to a different component

Comment: Should submit handler always be async, if there's an API call? -> yes, if you have to `await` for anything inside it ^^